# transfer data from SQL Server 2008 R2 to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

There is an external SQL server which is updated daily.

I need to update a MySQL DB based on the changes in SQL Server 2008 r2 data. What would be the best way to transfer the data daily? Is there a way to integrate those 2 platforms?

I was thinking about writing an app that would read the SQL server data, and then insert it into a MySQL db. Is it possible to implement or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Consider Microsoft's **Sql Server Integration Services (SSIS)**.  This is a very powerful tool that allows you to move data between two databases, among many other things.  You could create and schedule an job on the SQL Server to execute a SSIS pacakge to transfer data daily.  The benefit here is you don't need to write a custom app--and SSIS has a nice GUI for defining the steps in the data transfer.  Without knowing the constraints of your systems, I don't know what you may or may not be limited to, but at least consider this tool as one good option.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about this (I haven't tried it but sounds promising...)?
http://sourceforge.net/projects/nautilus/

...and please, feel free to use my old script we used when we replaced mssql with mysql. Hard work but the best move ever!

http://varuste.net/show_create_table.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Openquery" in SQL Server.

- install mysql odbc,  http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/
- create linked server in SQL Server
- then use openquery select statements

for select statement(Query to be run on sql server)
select * 
from openquery(your_linked_server_name, 'select * from mysql_table')

for insert statement
insert into openquery(your_linked_server_name, 'select * from mysql_table')
      select * from sql_server_table